# Button which adds additional form

Tags: php, html

What I'm trying to do is to have two buttons under form. One which validates it (required fields) and then submits. And another one which validates is (again required fields) and then adds additional form (for additional address), but the thing is that every time the second button is clicked it should add form.

I need to do it only with HTML and PHP.

My HTML:

```
form  id="form" method="post">
                Адрес ред 1                 <span class="alert"> * <?php echo $address_line_1Err ?></span>           <input type="text" name="address_line_1" /><br>
                Адрес ред 2                 <input type="text" name="addres_line_2" /><br>
                Пощенски код                <span class="alert"> * <?php echo $address_zipErr ?></span>           <input type="text" name="address_zip" /><br>
                Населено място              <span class="alert"> * <?php echo $address_cityErr ?></span>            <input type="text" name="address_city" /><br>
                Област                      <span class="alert"> * <?php echo $address_provinceErr ?></span>           <input type="text" name="address_province" /><br>
                Държава                     <input type="text" name="address_country" /><br><br>
                <span class="alert"> * Полетата са задължителни </span><br><br><br><br>
                <input  class="submit1" id="submit1" type="submit" value="Стъпка 3" name="submit" >
                <input type="submit" id="add" name="add" value="Допълнителен адрес" />
```

My PHP:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

            if(empty($_POST["address_line_1"])) {
                $address_line_1Err = "Адрес е задължителен";
            }  
            if(empty($_POST["address_zip"])) {
                $address_zipErr = "Пощенски код е задължителен";
            }
            if(empty($_POST["address_city"])) {
                $address_cityErr = "Населено място е задължително";
            }
            if(empty($_POST["address_province"])) {
                $address_provinceErr = "Област е задължителна";
            } else {
                header('Location: step3.php');
            }}
```

Comment: didn't get your question. Do you mean, on second button click, form doesnot gets add ?

Comment: I mean that I have 2 buttons and the second one should add the same form. @Khushboo

Comment: you can use hide/show using jquery/ajax

Comment: I need to do it with PHP becouse I'm on practics and that's the task :#. Too easy with jQuery :D @Khushboo

Answer (score 0):

Try below. Add below code before your submit button :-

```
if(isset($_POST["add"])){
                Адрес ред 1                 <span class="alert"> * <?php echo $address_line_1Err ?></span>           <input type="text" name="address_line_1" /><br>
                Адрес ред 2                 <input type="text" name="addres_line_2" /><br>
                Пощенски код                <span class="alert"> * <?php echo $address_zipErr ?></span>           <input type="text" name="address_zip" /><br>
                Населено място              <span class="alert"> * <?php echo $address_cityErr ?></span>            <input type="text" name="address_city" /><br>
                Област                      <span class="alert"> * <?php echo $address_provinceErr ?></span>           <input type="text" name="address_province" /><br>
                Държава                     <input type="text" name="address_country" /><br><br>

}
```

Comment: Works, but only adds it one time. After the second form shows if I click it again nothing happens.

Comment: you want to add multiple times ?

Comment: Yep. Everytime the button is clicked to another form to be added. I know it's unnecessary but that's my task. @Khushboo